# how to serialize form like this?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, c#-3.0

i know there is ton of question like this, but i cannot find solution sorry newbie...
i have form where row can be added and removed through javascript

```
<form id="form1">
    <div class="row">
         <input name="suppliername" />
         <input name="supplierproduct" />
    <div>
     <div class="row">
         <input name="suppliername" />
         <input name="supplierproduct" />
    <div>
    <div class="row">
         <input name="suppliername" />
         <input name="supplierproduct" />
    <div>
</form>
```

i need serialize this form become array of object like below

```
var data = [{suppliername : 'sup1', supplierproduct : 'prod1'}, {suppliername : 'sup1', supplierproduct : 'prod1'}, {suppliername : 'sup1', supplierproduct : 'prod1'}]
```

and i will post that data throuhg jquery ajax post..... ? 
server will use asp mvc ..

controller

```
public void createsup(List<Supplier> model)
{
    // something
}
```

SupplierClass

```
public class Supplier
{
    public string suppliername {get; set;}
    public string supplierproduct{get; set;}
}
```

help thanks...

Comment: Why are you creating manual html. Use `@model List<Supplier>` in your view and generate your html using html helpers in a `for` loop so they have the correct name attributes. The all you need is `data: $('form').serialize()` to post it using ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `map()` to create an array of objects containing those properties and values from the `input` fields within a `.row`. Try this:

```
var data = $('.row').map(function() {
    var obj = {};
    $(this).find('input').each(function() {
        obj[this.name] = this.value;
    });
    return obj;
}).get();
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/81qjq1oe/)